# Object detection slow and does not use GPU

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, image-recognition, object-detection-api

I need to use Tensorflow Object Detection API to make some classification connected with recognition.

My problem is that using the API for detection with a pretrained coco model takes too much time and for sure does not use the GPU. I checked my tensorflow-gpu installation on different scripts and it works fine, but when I use this model for detection I can only see increse in CPU usage.

I checked different version of tensorflow (1.12, 1.14), different combinations of CUDA Toolkit (9.0, 10.0) and CuDNN (7.4.2, 7.5.1, 7.6.1) but it is all the same, also tried it on both Windows 7 and Ubuntu 16.04, no difference. My project however requires much faster detection time.

System information:
System: Windows 7, Ubuntu 16.04
Tensorflow: 1.12, 1.14
GPU: GTX 970

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run following python code, if it detects GPU then you can use GPU for training otherwise there is some problem,

```
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
print(device_lib.list_local_devices())
```

One more thing, just because your CPU is utilizing does not mean GPU is not at work. CPU always be busy, GPU should also spike when you are training.

Paste the output of above code in the comment if you are not sure about the output.

Edit: After chat with OP on comments, I see the suggested code, and it is using pretrained model, so no training happening here. You are *using* model and not training a new model. So no gpu is being used.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
[name: "/device:CPU:0"
device_type: "CPU"
memory_limit: 268435456
locality {
}
incarnation: 12868789687935921631
, name: "/device:GPU:0"
device_type: "GPU"
memory_limit: 3546435584
locality {
  bus_id: 1
  links {
  }
}
incarnation: 5695922347637991756
physical_device_desc: "device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 970, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 5.2"
]

Comment: I also checked the usage of GPU with GPU-Z software for monitoring GPU work and I did not notice even a small spike or VRAM utilisation.

Comment: Yes, the output is correct, it is suggesting you can use GPU, not sure what is wrong if possible can you paste your code, also try using google colab if you still face same issue there.

Comment: Right now I only use the exemplary code from delivered with the library Jupyter Notebook object_detection_tutorial.ipynb. I just wanted to use it to check how long does it take to make the detections, since it is crucial for my project. I see some people on the internet report something like even 10 detections per second, when I get 1 detection in 5 seconds.

Comment: @Makintosz Ah!, you are not training you are using pretrained model. Look at my answer. I have edited it, you are not training model here so no GPU will be required. Please accept the answer, if I have solved your problem.

Comment: Yes, I am using it for detection, I thought I explained it good enough in sentence: "My problem is that detection of a pretrained coco model takes too much time".

Does it mean that during the actual using of any pretrained model object detection will only be using CPU? So why others get results tens of times faster than I do on the same model? So maybe training my own model can help?

Comment: Yes, you mentioned about pretrained model, but usually, people download pretrained model then train it for there use. But not required if model is matching your expectations. Yes, if you do not need to train it, CPU will be used.

Comment: So to make it perfectly clear to me, tf object detection api does not use GPU in actuall detection of the objects, only in training?

Comment: Your model is already trained, no need to train it again using GPU. For instance in your Andriod phone there are many pretrained model, they run without GPU, as they are already trained.